# IIS seems to suddenly lose ability to access the database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, iis-8, .net-4.6

I recently upgraded a VS2010 project to VS2015 and .NET 4.6.1, accessing SQL Server.  I'm getting a strange error intermittently.

If I empty out the folder that IIS is pointing to and then copy everything into that, the site is able to access the database just fine.

My deployment script copies from a newly published folder into that folder.  It appears that when that occurs, the site can no longer access the database, and I get an Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object error.  This results from a query of a lookup table that returns no results, when it's just a lookup table.

One possible thought was that the web.config file used to have the username and password defined in the identity parameter with impersonate=true.  The username and password are defined in IIS, though, so it doesn't seem like this is necessary.

Again, when I empty the folder and then copy back into it, the site seems to work again.

UPDATE:  I just noticed an Event with an ID of 5011 on the server.  After this, it shows events with ID's of 1309.

Comment: Im guessing its not an SQL database, but something like access?

Comment: It actually is SQL Server.  Edited to include that.  @BugFinder

Comment: Are the web config files different when you manually copy them from when your script publish?

Comment: @MarcusH No.  In fact, when I copy the live folder while it's working and then point IIS to that new folder, that doesn't work either.

Comment: So it only fails when hosted by IIS?  App Pool identity issues?

Comment: Any SQL errors on the SQL server? to go with? to point out what its doing

Comment: Are you connecting to the database through Windows Auth or Server Auth?

Comment: Just updated the case... there is an Event with an ID of 5011 that occurred right when the issue arose.

Comment: If database connectivity issue is only after deploying to IIS, could you try setting App pool identity with your credentials/ the one given in connection string?

Comment: @Developer I'm not really sure what you mean by that.  Sorry, but I don't have much experience with IIS.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx - hope this will help..go for custom account and give your username and password